# Apache James Mail Server - Save attachments on filesystem

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-mail, james

I'm using Apache James version 3.0-beta1 and I would like to know if there is a way to save separately the body of the e-mails from the attachments. Right now both of them are saved inside the DB, that leads to a noticeable increase in the table size due to the fact that all the attachments are saved inside the MAIL_BYTES column in the shape of a byte stream.

Is there a way to move outside the DB the attachments and leave inside the DB only the body of the emails? On the long run this default behaviour will make my DB collapse.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply write a mailet to get the attachments of the mail and then save them to a specific folder in your filesystem. To be more specific, in mailet, get the MimeMessage from org.apache.mailet.Mail, then use it to check if there are any attachments by using getFileName() method. This method returns file names if Disposition and ContentType headers are not null . If the result is not null, then that means in than bodyPart you have a file attached.Then using getInputStream() you can save it to anywhere you want.